# Excel Line Chart Only Unique Dates

Tags: excel, date, format, linegraph

I have a set of data as follows:

```
Date    Amount
8/8/2013    $0.00
8/16/2013   $1.60
8/16/2013   $2.40
8/16/2013   $4.40
8/16/2013   $8.40
8/16/2013   $8.40
8/17/2013   $6.40
8/17/2013   $5.40
8/17/2013   $6.20
8/17/2013   $7.00
8/22/2013   $7.80
8/22/2013   $6.80
8/22/2013   $5.80
8/22/2013   $4.80
```

And I have a line chart set up to show the progress of the Amount over time. The problem I have is that the graph shows, for example, 4 different data points for 8/16/2013 instead of one.

I'd like the graph to display 4 data points, which will be the final amount for each unique date, as follows:

```
Date    Amount
8/8/2013    $0.00
8/16/2013   $8.40
8/17/2013   $7.00
8/22/2013   $4.80
```

How can I get the chart to do this?

Comment: Is a UDF amenable? Or should it be strictly formula-based?

Comment: Sorry for not responding, didn't see this. But yes I was hoping for formula based. Appreciate the reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subtotal Amount for each change in Date, filter to select the subtotals, replace the first visible amount with something like `=C2` and copy down to suit. Replace the text part of the Date Subtotal rows.

Comment: While not ideal (because I need to re-filter every time I add new data) this got me on the right track to finding a solution. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Even better, thank you! I didn't realize that the graph would ignore #N/A. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Didn't even see it until now.